# I created a repository about a month ago and now I tried to download It and opened get errors that some files are blocked. how to fix?

Tags: github, repository

my repository is set to private but even if i set it to public and tried to download it again when i opened it on visual studio community 2022 i'm getting many errors.  some packages are missing some files are blocked.

the repository i created it and uploaded it to github to my account about a month ago and it was working 100% on my pc.

so far I tried to download the repository as zip when it was private and public but nothing changed.

i tried to  make right click on the blocked files in the file explorer ,  there are two files one of them is form1.resx right click properties and checked the checkbox to unblock clicked apply but later i saw it become blocked again.

some packages are missing but the dll's are in my project referenced so I'm not sure if i need and why to install these packages over again.

i tried to google so some answer suggested to look for git folders in my files and folders when downloading the project but i don't have any files ending with .lock or any git folders.

i'm not going to build the whole project over again. there must be a way to fix it or at least to get some reason why it happened at all?

Comment: Please include the actual text printed as part of the error message by editing your post.  Ideally, try to reproduce it by cloning at the command line with `git clone URL`, and include all the output as a text block (not an image).